# Android apk missing source classes (compiling with maven)

Tags: android, maven

I'm building an Android application with Maven and Eclipse and I'm having a problem after deploying to Android. I'm using mvn clean install android:deploy to compile and deploy my app but although the apk is generated without any errors after uploaded to the phone I got a weird behaviour.

The app starts fine (it consists in some differents activities) and I can go though act. 1 to act. 2 and from act. 2 to act. 3 but when I try to go on from act. 3 to act. 4 the app stops with a "CLASS NOT FOUND" exception.

I'm really desperate as it's been a very long time trying to guess what is wrong with no avail, and one curious thing is if I look inside the target/classes the corresponding .class file causing the error is there!

I'm using Maven 3.1 and android-maven-plugin and my pom file is copied below. I'm really desperate as I'm not being able to find a solution so any help will be much appreciated.

Thankx in advance!

D.

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    com.myApp.myApp
    myApp
    1.0
    apk
    myApp

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <platform.version>4.1.1.4</platform.version>
    <android.plugin.version>3.8.1</android.plugin.version>
    <keystore.location>/home/myName/Documents/projects/MyApp/keystore/MyApp_keystore</keystore.location>
    <keystore.password></keystore.password>
    <keystore.keypass></keystore.keypass>
    <keystore.alias>myapp</keystore.alias>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
        <version>r7</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-android</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1-RC1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}_unsigned</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <sign>
                    <debug>false</debug>
                </sign>
                <sdk>
                    <platform>19</platform>
                </sdk>
                <zipalign>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <inputApk>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}_unsigned.apk</inputApk>
                    <outputApk>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}.apk</outputApk>
                </zipalign>
                <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>zipalign</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>zipalign</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>signing</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sign</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <inherited>true</inherited>
                    <configuration>
                        <removeExistingSignatures>true</removeExistingSignatures>
                        <archiveDirectory/>
                        <includes>
                            <include>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}.apk</include>
                        </includes>
                        <keystore>${keystore.location}</keystore>
                        <alias>${keystore.alias}</alias>
                        <storepass>${keystore.password}</storepass>
                        <keypass>${keystore.keypass}</keypass>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone is facing the same problem, finally and after one desperating week looking for a solution it turned out to be something quite stupid and simple.

The problematic class was using android-support and as in pom.xml I mistakenly included provided for android-support dependency this was making the android support jar not being included in maven dependencies folder so this was the problem, the class wasn't finding it.

The thing here is that the error was not clear because it was complaning about a missing class not a missing jar or something like that. It has been in front of my eyes but I wasn't seeing it.

I hope it helps someone with the same problem.